# SQl query conversion to Linq Error

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I wanted to convert the following sql query to Linq :-

```
exec('SELECT * FROM (SELECT MAS.EmployeeId, MAS.ENTRY_DATE, IT.InDate 
IN_DATE, OT.InDate OUT_DATE, MAS.SHIFT_CODE, MAS.SHIFT_FLAG, CASE WHEN 
(IT.InDate IS NOT NULL) AND (OT.INDATE IS NOT NULL) THEN CASE WHEN IT.InDate = OT.InDate THEN ''FALSE'' ELSE ''OK'' END ELSE  ''FAIL'' END AS VALID FROM (SELECT EmployeeId, Time_Date1 ENTRY_DATE,Time_Field1 SHIFT_CODE, Time_Field2 
SHIFT_FLAG FROM [WWEGG8f9bf41c16].[TO_TempInOutNew] GROUP BY EmployeeId, Time_Date1, Time_Field1, Time_Field2) MAS LEFT JOIN [WWEGG8f9bf41c16].[TO_TempInOutNew] IT ON IT.EmployeeId=MAS.EmployeeId AND 
IT.Time_Date1=MAS.ENTRY_DATE AND IT.InOutFlag=''I'' LEFT JOIN [WWEGG8f9bf41c16].[TO_TempInOutNew] OT ON OT.EmployeeId=MAS.EmployeeId AND OT.Time_Date1=MAS.ENTRY_DATE AND OT.InOutFlag=''O'') MY_IN_OUT')
```

So I did this with the help of Linqer :-

```
var qry = (from MY_IN_OUT in
                               (
                                   (from MAS in
                                        (
                                            (from TO_TempInOutNew in listTempInOutNew
                                             group TO_TempInOutNew by new
                                             {
                                                 TO_TempInOutNew.EmployeeId,
                                                 TO_TempInOutNew.Time_Date1,
                                                 TO_TempInOutNew.Time_Field1,
                                                 TO_TempInOutNew.Time_Field2
                                             } into g
                                             select new
                                             {
                                                 g.Key.EmployeeId,
                                                 ENTRY_DATE = g.Key.Time_Date1,
                                                 SHIFT_CODE = g.Key.Time_Field1,
                                                 SHIFT_FLAG = g.Key.Time_Field2
                                             }))
                                    join IT in listTempInOutNew
                                          on new { EmployeeId = Convert.ToInt32(MAS.EmployeeId), Time_Date1 = Convert.ToDateTime(MAS.ENTRY_DATE), InOutFlag = "I" }
                                      equals new { IT.EmployeeId, IT.Time_Date1, IT.InOutFlag } into IT_join
                                    from IT in IT_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                    join OT in listTempInOutNew
                                          on new { EmployeeId = Convert.ToInt32(MAS.EmployeeId), Time_Date1 = Convert.ToDateTime(MAS.ENTRY_DATE), InOutFlag = "O" }
                                      equals new { OT.EmployeeId, OT.Time_Date1, OT.InOutFlag } into OT_join
                                    from OT in OT_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        EmployeeId = (int?)MAS.EmployeeId,
                                        ENTRY_DATE = (DateTime?)MAS.ENTRY_DATE,
                                        IN_DATE = (DateTime?)IT.InDate,
                                        OUT_DATE = (DateTime?)OT.InDate,
                                        MAS.SHIFT_CODE,
                                        MAS.SHIFT_FLAG,
                                        VALID =
                                        IT.InDate != null &&
                                        OT.InDate != null ? (
                                        IT.InDate == OT.InDate ? "FALSE" : "OK") : "FAIL"
                                    }))
                           select new
                           {
                               MY_IN_OUT.EmployeeId,
                               MY_IN_OUT.ENTRY_DATE,
                               MY_IN_OUT.IN_DATE,
                               MY_IN_OUT.OUT_DATE,
                               MY_IN_OUT.SHIFT_CODE,
                               MY_IN_OUT.SHIFT_FLAG,
                               MY_IN_OUT.VALID
                           }).ToList();
```

It gives me error at position `OUT_DATE = (DateTime?)OT.InDate,`. 
OT.InDate is shown null. which shouldn't be the case.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: why complicate it, complex queries like this should not be implemented using linq, use ADO instead.

Comment: If you get allow null values, and you do since you defined a nullable DateTime object, you should do validations. Why not condition your LINQ with IF statements in relevant places? or Where clause filtering if you do not allow nulls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Left Join so object IT and OT could be null.
Replace the select Part as below.

```
select new
           {
        EmployeeId = (int?)MAS.EmployeeId,
        ENTRY_DATE = (DateTime?)MAS.ENTRY_DATE,
        IN_DATE = (DateTime?)IT != null ? IT.InDate : null,
        OUT_DATE = (DateTime?)OT != null ? OT.InDate : null,
        MAS.SHIFT_CODE,
        MAS.SHIFT_FLAG,
        VALID =
        IT != null && IT.InDate != null &&
        OT != null && OT.InDate != null ? (
        IT.InDate == OT.InDate ? "FALSE" : "OK") : "FAIL"
           }))
```